# Functions with different return types and parameteres C++

Tags: c++, function, types, parameters, return

I need an answer for this C++ question, I have worked on it, but clearly im missing something and I will post my answer so far too....

Write a program that will calculate and print pay slips.

User inputs are the name of the employee, the number of hours worked and the hourly pay rate.

You have to declare three functions:

1) one for input;

2) one to calculate the employees pay; and

3) one to print the payslip

The user has to input the name of the employee, the number of hours worked and the hourly pay rate into the variables `theEmployee`, `theHoursWorked` and `thePayRate`. The variable `employee` is a `string` and the other two variables are of the type `float`. As the values of theEmployee, theHoursWorked and thePayRate will be changed in this function, `reference parameters need to be used`.

The calculation function will receive two parameters that represent the number of hours worked and the hourly pay rate, do the calculation and return the pay for the employee. An employee who has worked more than 40 hours is paid 1.5 times the hourly pay rate for each hour of the overtime. As the parameters are not changed in the function, they should be value parameters. The function should return a `float` value which represents the pay.

The output function has to display the name of the employee, the number of hours worked, the number of overtime hours and the hourly pay rate entered by the user as well as the employee's pay. for

Example:

Pay slip for Pink Panther

Hours worked: 43.5 hours

Overtime hours: 3.5 hours

Hourly pay rate: R125.35

Pay: R5672.09

The main function includes a for loop that allows the user to repeat the calculation of a pay slip for five employees.

```
int main()
{
string theEmployee;
float theHoursWorked;
float thePayRate;
int thePay;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    getData(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
    thePay = calculatePay (theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
    printPaySlip(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate, thePay);
}

return 0;
}
```

THATS WHAT THEY GAVE, this is what I have done so far, I guess that I am struggling with the reference parameters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getData (string & theEmployee , float & theHoursWorked, float & thePayRate)
{
cout<< "Enter your name and surname: "<< endl;
getline(cin, theEmployee);

cout << "Include the numbers of hours you worked: " << endl;
cin >> theHoursWorked;

cout << "What is your hourly pay rate?" << endl;
cin >> thePayRate;

return theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate;

}

float calculatePay( string & theEmployee, float & theHoursWorked, float & thePayRate)
{
float tempPay, thePay, overtimeHours;
if (theHoursWorked > 40)
    {
    tempPay = 40 * thePayRate;
    overtimeHours = theHoursWorked - 40;
    thePay = tempPay + overtimeHours;}
else
    thePay = theHoursWorked * thePayRate;
    return thePay;
}

int printPaySlip( string & theEmployee, float & theHoursWorked, float &    
thePayRate, float thePay)
{
float overtimeHours;
cout << "Pay slip for " << theEmployee <<endl;
cout << "Hours worked: "<< theHoursWorked << endl;
if (theHoursWorked > 40)
    overtimeHours = theHoursWorked - 40;
else
    overtimeHours = 0;
cout << "Overtime hours: "<< overtimeHours << endl;
cout << "Hourly pay rate: " << thePayRate << endl;
cout << "Pay: " << thePay << endl;
cout << endl;

}


int main()
{
string theEmployee;
float theHoursWorked;
float thePayRate;
int thePay;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    getData(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
    thePay = calculatePay (theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
    printPaySlip(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate, thePay);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you aren't calculating pay rate for overtime hours correctly - you should multiply `overtimeHours` by pay rate times 1.5 as the problem states, instead of simply adding it to the pay.

Answer (score 0):

No need for return in the getData functrion. This should work

```
void getData (string & theEmployee , float & theHoursWorked, float & thePayRate)
{
    cout<< "Enter your name and surname: "<< endl;
    getline(cin, theEmployee);

    cout << "Include the numbers of hours you worked: " << endl;
    cin >> theHoursWorked;

    cout << "What is your hourly pay rate?" << endl;
    cin >> thePayRate;

}
```

Note the getData function is declared void, which means strictly speaking it does not return a value. In your problem spec 'return' is being used loosely to mean a value which a function calculates and then gives back to the calling function, it's doesn't mean you have to have an actual `return` in your code.

BTW not the qestion you asked but you are going to have trouble because you are mixing `getline` with `>>`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336209/mixing-ifstream-getline-and) for an explanation.

Comment: Also function `printPaySlip` should return void.

Comment: Hi
Thank you so much for the informative feedback, but it still doesn't let me input a second round of names and stuff, if you compile and run it you will see! I don't understand. After it you do a first round of values and stuff it ends and starts again, but on the 3rd line, skipping name and hours?:(

Comment: @user2257336 As I said in my answer that's because you are mixing getline with >>. This problem has been asked hundreds of times here. I can't answer it any better than all the answers that have already been given. Have a look at the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

First, `getData` and `printPaySlip` functions shouldn't return anything - return type should be changed from `int` to `void`.

Second, the line `return theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate` is an error and should be removed - C++ doesn't allow multiple return values, and uses reference parameters instead. This means that the function is allowed to modify its parameters. You already read them correctly, so simply remove the `return` line.

Third, the `calculatePay` and `printPaySlip` functions do not require references, as they do not modify the parameters. Even the problem statement says they should take values, so simply remove the `&`'s.

Fourth, your `calculatePay` function calculates the rate for overtime hours incorrectly - it simply adds the amount of overtime hours to the total pay without multiplying it by `thePay * 1.5`.